# Layout not shifting up when keyboard is open

Tags: java, android, xml, keyboard, android-edittext

In my app, I have a few TextViews above an EditText. When the EditText is focused and the keyboard is open, I want all of the views to shift upwards so they are all still visible. I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the Manifest file, and the views do shift up the first time I the EditText is focused. However, any subsequent time, all of the views stay in the same place, making the EditText covered by the keyboard. How do I make this work indefinitely?

Here is the XML for the EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

Comment: try this in androidmanifest file   <activity name="YourActivityTryingToResize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">

Comment: @ASP This moves my Edittext to the top of the screen, it does not shift everything upwards.

Comment: ASP's answer is correct. You need to add this line to AndroidManifest. "adjustPan" anchors the view. The keyboard comes to the front of the view and hides the content that lays its back. The problem should be about the layout you used.

Comment: @Dorukhan Arslan When I try ASP's suggestion, the edit texts go above the text views when I want it below them

Comment: Can you add a screenshot if it is possible?

Comment: Hey..Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: @AbhayBohra It's been almost two years since I worked on this project so I don't remember, sorry.